# Parse a skype log

Tags: php, regex, skype

I need to parse a skype log, grab all the call durations and add them up and find out the total duration of calls for the entire chat history.

Sample:

[3/12/2012 11:36:44 AM] *** Call ended, duration 21:33 ***

I think I need to use preg_match with the proper regex expression. If it's possible to store the actual timestamp in array at the same time that would be better.

I think what i'm really stumped on is the actual regex rule that's needed to grab just the call duration.

Comment: would grabbing the last 7 characters on a line removing space and asterix work?

Comment: @Dagon No, there may come an hour field.

Comment: everything post "duration" and a little clean up then

Comment: actully is the * the op formatting ? or the actual file?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
(?i)\[(?P<time_stamp>[^[]+)\]\s*[*]\s*[a-z ,]+(?P<duration>(?:\d{2}:?){2,3})\s*[*]
```

**Explanation**

```
"
(?i)               # Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i)
\[                 # Match the character “[” literally
(?P<time_stamp>    # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “time_stamp”
   [^[]               # Match any character that is NOT a “[”
      +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\]                 # Match the character “]” literally
\s                 # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
[*]                # Match the character “*”
\s                 # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
[a-z ,]            # Match a single character present in the list below
                      # A character in the range between “a” and “z”
                      # One of the characters “ ,”
   +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?P<duration>      # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “duration”
   (?:                # Match the regular expression below
      \d                 # Match a single digit 0..9
         {2}                # Exactly 2 times
      :                  # Match the character “:” literally
         ?                  # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   ){2,3}             # Between 2 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\s                 # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   *                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
[*]                # Match the character “*”
"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 \*.+?([0-9]+:){1,2}([0-9]+)
```

Then it can catch both HH:MM:SS and MM:SS that comes after the first `*`.

Comment: wont that grab the time stamp to ?